# Instances of substrings in larger strings

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code using a nested for loop that will return how many instances of a substring appear in a larger string.

I.e. if the string is "*selfish sailfish relish shellfish*" and I am searching for occurence of "*sh*" the expected result is 5.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       String sub = "sh";
       String str = "selffish sailfish relish shellfish";
       int count = 0;
       str = str.toLowerCase();
       sub = sub.toLowerCase();
       for (int i =  0; i < str.length(); i++)
       {
            if (str.charAt(i) == sub)
            {
                count++;
            }
       }
       System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far. Logically it wont work because it is comparing a string to a a char. Is there another comparison I can use in place of charAt(i) to get it to work?

Comment: Why does it return 5?

Comment: What i have tried so far is searching among the various substring questions on this site and it has not become much clearer.
And it returns 5 because that is how many instances of "sh". Sorry i forgot to include that part. Im new here dont hate me.

Comment: @Hayden I suppose the searched string in his example is "sh"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.indexOf()` for that:

```
public static int nrTimes(final String needle, final String haystack)
{
    if (needle.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    if (haystack.isEmpty())
        return 0;

    final int len = needle.length();

    int ret = 0;
    int index = 0;

    while ((index = haystack.indexOf(needle, index)) != -1) {
        ret++;
        index += len;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Except that it seems the OP want to write it using nested loops, this is the best way to do it.

Comment: I agree with @Jean-FrançoisSavard, but will add, please don't give spoon-feed the required solution.